# Combinatorics Problem with Chess

Tags: probability, combinatorics

8 black and 8 white pawns (totally 16 pawns) are placed at random on a chess board (64 squares with 8 rows and 8 columns). What is the probability that there is at least one row which has exactly 3 black pawns and 3 white pawns?

I thought that with this problem, the denominator would be the C(16,64)*C(8,16) for the numerator - I just do not know how to divide the cases.

Comment: Suppose the first row has exactly three black and three white pawns.  Decide how those six pawns are distributed on that row.  Then decide how to distribute the remaining ten pawns over the remaining seven rows.  Continue by applying inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: I just stuck on the process of calculating the distribute of the remaining ten paws since they may become exactly 3 black pawns and 3 white pawns on another row or not, I think there are so many cases and I don't know how to solve that, thanks

Comment: @Bean007 The point that you could get exactly 3 black and 3 white on another row doesn't matter at the moment because that is exactly what inclusion-exclusion protects against.  There are $64-8=56$ remaining spaces, five black pawns and five white pawns.  Later on in the inclusion-exclusion process we'll actually care about getting exactly three black and exactly three white on multiple rows.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_i$ represent the event that row $i$ has exactly three black and three white pawns.

We are asked to count $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_8|$

By [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) this is

$$=|A_1|+\dots+|A_8|-|A_1\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_3|-\dots-|A_7\cap A_8|+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|+\dots$$

By symmetry, we notice that $|A_1|=|A_2|=\dots=|A_8|$ and that $|A_1\cap A_2|=|A_1\cap A_3|=\dots=|A_7\cap A_8|$ etc... so the above simplifies to:

$$=8|A_1|-28|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|+\dots$$

Counting $|A_1|$:

- Arrange $3$ black and $3$ white pawns in the first row.
- Arrange the remaining $5$ black and $5$ white pawns in the remaining rows.

> This can be done in $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{56}{5}\binom{51}{5}$ ways

Counting $|A_1\cap A_2|$

- Arrange $3$ black and $3$ white pawns in the first row.
- Arrange $3$ black and $3$ white pawns in the second row.
- Arrange the remaining $2$ black and $2$ white pawns in the remaining rows.

Now, notice that it is impossible to have exactly three black and three white pawns in more than two rows at a time as that would require at least nine black pawns, which is more than our eight black pawns we have available.  This implies that all terms consisting of intersections of three or more of our events are empty and contribute zero to the overall sum.

Finish the arithmetic and take the appropriate ratio and reach a final answer.